# Adding attribute to points depending on underlying polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have two layers:

One, a point cloud of 300.000 points of trees.

Secondly, a layer with polygon which indicates the owner of a certain piece of ground on which the tree resides. I would like to add the owner to the rest of the attributes of the trees.

How can I best perform this action?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clip tool for this or maybe even [spatial join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) tool, alternatively if you convert your feature layer (polygons) into a raster you could also use extract by mask